# Algorithm: Find elements that appeared exactly twice

Tags: algorithm

**Input:** An unsorted integer array `A[1..n]` with only `O(d) :(d < < n)` distinct elements.

**Output:** All elements that appeared exactly twice.

Ask for two algorithms, one with `O(Nd)` and the other `O(Nlogd)`. Maximum number could be very large, so an array of size `n` counting the frequencies might not be a good idea. Any thought?

To clarify, "with only `O(d) :(d < < n)` distinct elements" means all other elements (not those `O(d)` ones) appeared twice or more.

Comment: I think it sounds like homework...

Comment: It was from an exam, I spent half an hour on this without luck. Give an answer with an array of size M to count the frequencies of all the numbers, where M is the maximum number which can be determined in O(n). But not sure how to use the O(d) thing.

Answer (score 1):

`O(nd)` is basically iterate all possible elements (`O(d)` of those) and count the number of times it repeats. each iteration is O(n)

`O(nlogd)` is to **build a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram)** (`map:int->int`) that counts how many times each element appears in the list in a single iteration. The map is [balanced Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) based to ensure `O(nlogd)`. Note that if you use a [hash map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) instead of a tree, it can be increased to `O(n)` average case (but `O(nd)` worst case)

**Psuedo code** - O(nlogd):

```
map <- new tree map
for each element x in list:
 if x is in map:
     map.put(x,map.get(x)+1)
 else:
     map.put(x,1)
for each (key,value) in map:
  if value == 2:
     print key
```

Comment: I didn't stat the problem explicitly, which should read "all other elements, except those O(d) ones, appeared twice or more".

Comment: @DavidTan: Both solutions are still valid with this addition.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array. O(nlogn)
Scan the array to find the elements which appeared only twice.O(n)

Repeating elements will be side by side.

O(n)+O(nlogn).

Comment: It does not satisfy the complexity requirements.

Comment: What is happen if in the problem is consider the sorting to be improper. Choosing in a set already sorted may be considered as an expensive solution in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution One O(N * d)

1. find all elements in the array whose value equal to A[0], count the
   number. If the number == 2, add it to the answer. Finally, erase all
   selected elements from the array.
2. Erase all same value elements would cause O(N) complexity, and this
   step1 should do d times, so the complexity is O(N * d).

### Solution Two O(N * logd)

Using a balanced tree to calculate the frequence of all value. Because there are only d dinstinct values, so the size of tree would be only d, and all operation on it will be logd. We insert all elements into the tree, and calculate the frequence of the node in the tree, total complexity is O(N * logd).

```
C++ code:

vector<long long> solve()
{
    vector<long long> ans;
    map<long long, int> cnt;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cnt[a[i]] += 1; // O(logd)
    for(map<long long, int>::iterator it = cnt.begin(); it != cnt.end(); ++it)
        if(it -> second == 2) ans.push_back(it -> first);
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: I didn't stat the problem explicitly, which should read "all other elements, except those O(d) ones, appeared twice or more".